# Is there any closed form for this summation :

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any closed form for this summation :

$$
\sum_{i_{1}\ +\ i_{2}\ +\ i_{3}\ =\ n
      \atop
      {\vphantom{\LARGE A}i_{k}\ \geq\ 0;\quad k\ =\ 1, 2, 3}}
\frac{2n!}{i_{1}!\, i_{1}!\, i_{2}!\, i_{2}!\, i_{3}!\, i_{3}!}$$

Comment: Just out of interest, where did it come from?

Comment: @TonyK: 3-dimensional random walk not recurrent. I want to prove that.

Comment: What does it describe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT :**
$$\sum_{i_{1}+i_{2}+i_{3}=n} \dfrac{(2n)!}{i_{1}!\,i_{1}!\,i_{2}!\,i_{2}!\,i_{3}!\,i_{3}!} = \binom{2n}{n}\sum_{i_{1}+i_{2}+i_{3}=n}\binom{n}{i_{1},i_{2},i_{3}}^{2}$$
where $\displaystyle \binom{n}{i_{1},i_{2},i_{3}}$ is the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

As far as I know there is no simple closed form for the RHS. However one can prove that

> $$\max_{i_{1}+i_{2}+\ldots +i_{d} = n} \binom{n}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots ,i_{d}} = \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{d^{n}}{n^{\frac{d-1}{2}}}\right)$$

Indeed if (to simplify), $\displaystyle i_{1} + i_{2} + \ldots + i_{d} = n = md$, then

$$ \binom{n}{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots ,i_{d}} \leq \binom{md}{m,m,\ldots,m}$$

and, using Stirling formula

$$\binom{md}{m,m,\ldots,m} \sim \dfrac{d^{\frac{d}{2}}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}}\dfrac{d^{md}}{(md)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\ds{{\cal I} \equiv \sum_{i_{1}\ +\ i_{2}\ +\ i_{3}\ =\ n
      \atop
      {\vphantom{\LARGE A}i_{k}\ \geq\ 0;\quad k\ =\ 1, 2, 3}}
\frac{2n!}{i_{1}!\, i_{1}!\, i_{2}!\, i_{2}!\, i_{3}!\, i_{3}!}}$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal I} &= \sum_{k_{1} = 0}^{n}\sum_{k_{2} = 0}^{n}\sum_{k_{3} = 0}^{n}
> \frac{2n!}{k_{1}!\, k_{1}!\, k_{2}!\, k_{2}!\, k_{3}!\, k_{3}!}\,
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,
> {1 \over z^{1 - k_{1} - k_{2} - k_{3} + n}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> 2n!\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{1 \over z^{n + 1}}\,
> \bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{z^{k} \over \pars{k!}^{2}}}^{3}
> \end{align}

The sum over $k$ is evaluated [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk+%3D+0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%28z%5E%7Bk%7D%2F%28k%21%29%5E2%29) in terms of a Bessel function and the hypergeometric function. That's what makes difficult to perform the integration.